# Issue with TensorFlow saving

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training neural nets with TensorFlow, and the model's training is working using a custom implementation of batch gradient descent. I have a logging function which records validation error, and it gets down to about 2.6%. I'm saving the model every 10 epochs using a `tf.train.Saver`.

However, when I load the variables into memory again using a `tf.train.Saver` with the same script, the model performs poorly--with about the performance it does when the weights are randomly initialized. I have inspected the constitutional filters in the checkpoint and they don't seem to be random however.

I have not included all of my code, since its around 400 lines long, but I've included what seem to be important sections here and summarized the other functionality.

```
class ModelTrainer:

    def __init__(self, ...hyperparameters...):

        # Intitialize datasets and hyperparameters

        for each gpu
            # Create loss function and gradient assigned to this gpu using tf.device("/gpu:n")

        with tf.device("/cpu:0")
            # Average and clip gradients from the gpu's

            # Create this batch gradient descent operation for each trainable variable
            variable.assign_sub(learning_rate * averaged_and_clipped_gradient).op


    def train(self, ...hyperparameters...)

        saver = train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), max_to_keep = 30)
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess = tf.Session()

        if starting_point is not None:  # Used to evaluate existing models
            saver.restore(sess, starting_point)
        else:
            sess.run(init)

        for i in range(number_of_batches)

            # ... Get training batch ...

            gradients = sess.run(calculate_gradients, feeds = training_batch)

            # Average "gradients" variable across multiple batches
            # Must be done because of GPU memory limitations

            if i % meta_batch_size == 0:
                sess.run(apply_gradients_operators,
                         feeds = gradients_that_have_been_averaged_across_multiple_batches)

            # Log validation error

            if i % save_after_n_batches == 0:
                saver.save(sess, "some-filename", global_step=self.iter_num)
```

As expected, running these two functions creates a set of checkpoint files called "some-filename-40001" or whatever other iteration number the training is at when that file is saved. Unfortunately when I load these checkpoints back in using the `start_point` parameter they perform on par with random initialization.

Initially I assumed it was something to do with the way I'm training the model, since I haven't found anyone else with this issue, but the validation error behaves as expected.

**Edit:** More odd results. After more experimentation, I have found that when I load the saved model using the code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved-checkpoint-40.meta")
    saver.restore(sess, "saved-checkpoint-40")

    # ... Use model in some way ...
```

I get different, but still incorrect results.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. My training script has both train and test phases. However when I loaded the saved model and evaluate it again on the same train and test data, both perform on par with random guess.